# Merge parent and child SQL Server tables that use identity keys

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have several big CSV files that I need to import into SQL Server 2016 Express.

These files are related by identity keys, for instace each item in `Documents.csv` relate by Pkey to an item in `Lines.csv` by Fkey. Natural keys (for intance Document Number) are not allowed as there can be duplicates.

I've imported these files into a SQL Server staging tables, using `SqlBulkCopy` in C#. The screenshot shows the relations between these staging tables:

[Table relations image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVIln.png)

Now I need to copy these tables to the final ones, in this process I need to create surrogate keys and mantain the former Id and Fkey columns. I've read that this can be achieved with merge and output, but I don't understand it fully.

Already tried a couple of times and the results are wrong - can you help on this?

Edit:
These imports are going to be performed multiple time by clients at any given time, so I must ensure that there are no colisions with the relationships.

I've got the correct results for the tables Documents and Lines using the query below. Now the question is, how do I do this at the same time for all tables (Files, DocumentTotals, so on...)? In fact, the Files table relates to all tables in the Database, this part is confusing for me, because when I perform the merge of Documents_staging into Documents I have to have already perform the mapping of Files table to relate the Files.Id's with all FileId's of all tables, correct? Thanks!

```
declare @match table
    (OriginalId int, insertedId int);

merge into dbo.Documents as tgt
using dbo.Documents_staging  as src
on 1 != 1 
when not matched then 
    insert
        (Number, Date)
    values
        (src.Number, Date)
output
    src.Id,
    inserted.Id
into
    @match; 

insert into Lines (Fkey, Number, Product)
select  m.insertedId
        ,lines.Number
        ,lines.Product
from
    Lines_Staging as lines
    left join @match  m
        on lines.Fkey = m.OriginalId
```

Comment: Are you having an issue with the SQL Database or just with c#?  I would move data from staging tables to final tables using SSMS with SQL scripts.  Will be much quicker.

Comment: I understand that you have problem because of identity which is returning after each insert. There is two approaches here: 1. you have to enable inserting identity straight from your staging table. Write this in google: "SQL Server SET IDENTITY_INSERT". If values are already used in production table you can offset your staging identity on about some value for example always +100000. 2. It is not efficient but if it will be run only once you can use cursor for the first table, insert the row one by one and fetch identity each time and inside set next cursor etc.

Comment: @jdweng: this must be done within c# invoking SQL queries.

Comment: @Arkadiusz: option 2 is an option that i've already implemented and thr performance is bad. Also tried with ORMs pulling back the identity created by sql and used in children. Again perfirmance is bad. CSV have +50 million rows.

Comment: You can have stored procedures in SQL Server and run the procedures from c# by using ExecuteNonQuery.    See method GetDepartments() at msdn : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx